# PDF returned from Remote method Loopback is corrupted

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, node-html-pdf

I am trying to return a file from my remote method:

```
Visitor.remoteMethod('getVisitorsPDF', {
    description: 'Get visitors list in PDF file',
    accepts: [
      { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } },
      { arg: 'dateInStart', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'dateInEnd', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'employeeSiteId', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'name', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'visitorCompany', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'employeeName', type: 'string' },
      { arg: 'typeId', type: 'number' },
      { arg: 'shift', type: 'number' },
    ],
    returns: {},
    http: { path: '/getpdf', verb: 'get' },
  });
```

And the code to generate pdf is :

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="visitors.pdf"');
let options = { format: 'A4' };
// Example of options with args //
// let options = { format: 'A4', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] };

let file = { content: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>" };
// or //
let file = { url: "https://example.com" };
html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
  console.log("PDF Buffer:-", pdfBuffer);
  res.send(pdfBuffer);
});
```

But the pdf recieve is corrupted. What i am doing wrong here ? any help will be appreciated. The package i am using is [html-pdf-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different package to render pdf (jsreport) but the headers should not differ:

```
res.set('Content-Type', renderedData.headers['content-type']);
res.set('Content-Disposition', renderedData.headers['content-disposition']);
res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
```

Try to add the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" one.